# Get Facebook ID with Opengraph using JQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I tried to grab my Facebook ID using open graph API. It is working if i use browser and browse to:
https://graph.facebook.com/IvanKristiantoBlog

But i want to grab it using JQuery, here is my sample code:
http://jsbin.com/ejogu3/2/edit
But when i debug using Firebug, not data return.
Do i miss something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually Javascript does not allow cross-domain request due the same-domain-policy. 
If I see it right you try to do so.
Better way would be to make the request on the server side.

But there are ways to make cross-domain request in JS.
check this:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: Yes! I don't why i forget this. probably i'm too tired. Thanks very much, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use /me instead of your name... This should fix it because you need to provide the numeric id and not the custom screen name.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Scroll down to the second set of links and click on the first link for friends which will have your access token if you are logged in to Facebook.

```
Friends: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...
```

Comment: Thanks but it need to use Facebook Apps. I just want to find to facebook ID. and it works without create an Facebook Apps. it is not working because cross domain policy. You guys just open my mind. Thanks.

Comment: There is a javascript SDK for the Graph API. Every Canvas page of every app is going to be "cross-domain" because the canvas pages are on the developer's server.

Comment: Yes but we still need to create our application and use the app id. I manage to get it working. i just make another php file that use curl to get the data. and return just the id. So my jquery script only get the data from that php file.

Comment: Yeah, thats a good way too... Also, once you have the ID, you can use the obsolete but not yet replaced pages.IsFan in order to see if the person likes your page. Then you can display different things accordingly... Just some input as I get that a lot as the next step.

Comment: I just need the facebook id to use in Facebook open graph meta tags. I create a WordPress plugin to do it. and one of the feature is an helper to get Facebook ID from facebook username. Just that simple. btw you can see the plugin here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-open-graph-meta-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

You can't fetch normal JSON content from other domains. Have a read about [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but the long story short, if you intend to fetch the data from another domain than yours, you need to have it in JSONP format.

As Facebook doesn't provide the Graph API in JSONP format, you will need to either use your own proxy or a proxy like the one Yahoo offers.